# How to find cause of hardware connect/disconnect sound?

Tags: 22.04

At random points during the day, I will hear the system sound that indicates that hardware has disconnected. Then after a second or two, I will hear the hardware connected sound.

It happens when I am not actively doing anything other than typing on the keyboard. It also happens sometimes when I am just passively listening to meetings.

How can I debug what caused that sound to occur?

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Gnome 42.5.

Comment: Start with your logs: Review /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [a comment by user535733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456029/how-to-find-cause-of-hardware-connect-disconnect-sound#comment2545280_1456029), as soon as I heard it happen again, I went and looked in `/var/log/syslog` and discovered the culprit.

I also came across [the `gnome-logs` tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Logs) that shows system logs in a spiffy UI. This tool made it easy to go back and see the other times it had happened.

(In my case, the problem appears to be a DVD burner that does not support low power modes. When the OS tries to power it down, there is an error.)